How to Prevent user from taking screenshot of Glance Widget?
I have already created Glance App Widget but it contain secure data how I can prevent user from taking screenshot of it. the whole widget or part of it ?
the sensitive or secure image is not screenshot able in app, but in widget it screenshot able

How can you stop them from using a second phone or camera to take a picture of the first one?

Even if it's possible, it's illegal. How can an app be granted permission to block users like that?


how I can prevent user from taking screenshot of it

That is not possible. The app widget UI is being displayed by the launcher app, not your app. You have no control or authority over whether the launcher app supports screenshots.

This currently seems not to be possible. To block screenshots of an Activity, we need to call
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

Here, window is a property on the android.app.Activity class. The obstacle is that within your glance widget, you only have an Application Context, and not an Activity Context, so you can't obtain the window property from it.
If you try
override suspend fun provideGlance(context: Context, id: GlanceId) {

    (context as Activity).window.setFlags(        // ClassCastException
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE
    )

    provideContent {
        // create your AppWidget here
        Text(text = "Hello World")
    }
}

You will receive a ClassCastException similar to this:
Error in Glance App Widget                                                                                               
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

